# Is there an operator precedence problem I'm missing? Compare of unsigned short with inverse fails

Tags: c++, c

I can THINK of why this wouldn't work, but I don't understand why many of the workarounds I've tried don't work.  Below is an example of the code I'm trying to make work.  The intent should be obvious, but compiling with GCC 7.4.0 for Windows 32 bit, Visual C 32 bit and Visual C 64 bit as well as the same compilers in C++ modes, all of them result in the same answer, so I'm sure it's not just a compiler bug.

The code is:

```
unsigned short usAlgo = 0x0001;
unsigned short usNotAlgo = ~usAlgo;

if ( usAlgo == ~usNotAlgo )
    printf("Pass\n");
else
    printf("Fail\n");
```

On all the compilers I've tried, this code prints "Fail".  By a slight rearrangement to:

```
unsigned short usCheck = ~usNotAlgo;
if ( usAlgo == usCheck )
```

It prints "Pass".  I would have thought the usCheck would get optimized out anyway, so why is this different?

I have tried all kinds of workarounds that don't work, with bit masking, parentheses, making them signed values, and such like:

```
if ( usAlgo == (~usNotAlgo) & 0xffff )
```

or

```
if ( (unsigned int)(usAlgo) == ~(unsigned int)(usNotAlgo) )
```

I think I've discovered that the first of those two fails because '==' has a higher order of precedence than '&', but I can't for the life of me understand why the simple:

```
if ( usAlgo == ~usNotAlgo )
```

fails.

Looking at the compiler output doesn't REALLY help, other than I can see the "real" comparison ends up being:

```
if( 0x00000001 == 0xFFFF0001 )
```

implying, the unsigned short (0xFFFE) was first promoted to an unsigned int (0x0000FFFE) and THEN negated.  (That's why we thought making them signed might sign extend to 0xFFFFFFFE.

I obviously have the answer to how to fix this, but I need to understand WHY.

Any ideas?

[Edit: Grammar]

Comment: In this case, `if ( usAlgo == (unsigned short)(~usNotAlgo) )` should work, no?

Comment: See https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP14-C.+Beware+of+integer+promotion+when+performing+bitwise+operations+on+integer+types+smaller+than+int - Applying the operation `~` promotes the `unsigned short` to `int`, as per § 6.3.1.1 in [ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1539.pdf)

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks, yeah, that works too - I've got various workarounds.  I just want to know why.

Comment: @CherryDT That second link seems like it's the right thing.  I'm going to have to try a bunch of my various "failed attempts" out to see if that answers everything.  Strange I've been coding ion C for 30 years and never run into that!

Comment: Some compiler warns about signed/unsigned comparison which is really helpful.

Comment: Is this C or C++ question? I think C and C++ are different in this manner.

Comment: @0x476f72616e Didn't seem to matter in my testing.

Answer (score 5):

As you have noticed, `usNotAlgo` was promoted to type `int` before the `~` operator was applied.  Generally speaking, anytime a type smaller than `int` is used in an expression, it is first promoted to `int`.

This is documented in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or
> `unsigned int` may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less
>   than  or  equal  to  the  rank  of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`,or `unsigned int`.
>
> If  an `int` can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as
> restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is
> converted  to  an `int`; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an
> `unsigned int`. These  are  called  the *integer promotions*. All
> other  types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions.

Section 6.5.3.3p4 regarding the `~` operator specifically says:

> **The result of the `~` operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand** (that is,each bit in the result is set if and
> only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not  set).
> **The  integer  promotions  are  performed  on  the  operand,  and  the
> result  has  the promoted type.**  If the promoted type is an unsigned
> type, the expression `~E` is equivalent to the maximum value
> representable in that type minus `E`.

This can be fixed by casting the result back to `unsigned short` to mask off the additional bits:

```
if ( usAlgo == (unsigned short)~usNotAlgo )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by writing ~usNotAlgo in the if statement, it got promoted to an int value, and then because of comparison, usAlgo value got promoted to int as well. This is why you see  `if(0x00000001 == 0xFFFF0001)` output from the compiler (instead of expected `if( 0x0001 == 0x0001 )`).

In order to fix it, cast ~usNotAlgo to unsigned short:

```
if (usAlgo == (unsigned short)~usNotAlgo) {code...}
```